# Copying files with different extensions

Tags: perl, scripting, network-programming

I am new to perl and i am trying to create a script which can copy several files with different extensions from one directory to another. I am trying to use an Array but not sure if this is possible but i am open to other ways if it is easier.

My code looks something like this;

```
my $locationone = "filepath"
my $locationtwo = "filepath"

my @files = ("test.txt", "test.xml", "test.html");

if (-e @files){
    rcopy($locationone, $locationtwo)
}
```

The code might be a little rough because i'm going off the top of my head and i'm still new to perl.

I'd really appreciate the help.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original idea you have, is right, but it misses something.

```
 ...
use File::Copy; # you will use this for the copy!
 ...
my $dest_folder = "/path/to/dest/folder";
my @sources_filenames = ("test.txt", "test.xml", "test.html");
my $source_folder = "/path/to/source/folder";
```

We set some useful variables: folder names and an array of file names.

```
foreach my $filename (@sources_filename) {
```

We run into the file names

```
  my $source_fullpath = "$source_folder/$filename"; # you could use
  my $dest_fullpath = "$dest_folder/$filename"; # File::Spec "catfile" too.
```

Then we build (*for each file*) a full path starting name and a full path destination name.

```
  copy($source_fullpath, $dest_fullpath) if -e $source_fullpath;
```

Lastly *we copy* only if file exists.

```
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
foreach my $file (@files)
{
     next unless (-e "$locationone/$file");
     `mv $locationone/$file $locationtwo`;
}
```